# Regex Javascript Match string by first two characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I have to match a string by it's first two letters using Regex to check a specific two characters available as the first two letters of a string. 
Here assume that the first two characters are 'XX'.

And the strings I need to match are

- ABCDS
- XXDER
- DERHJ
- XXUIO

So I need to filter this list to get strings that only starts with 'XX'

code I tried so far

```
var filteredArr = [];
var arr = [ "ABCDS ", "XXDER ", "DERHJ ", "XXUIO" ];
var re = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z]{2}');
jQuery.each( arr, function( i, val ) {

if(re.test(val )){
  filteredArr.push(val);
}
});
```

What will be the exact Regex pattern to check the string that starts with 'XX'

Comment: Do you want to check if first 2 characters are the same?

Comment: I recommend you these tools to avoid headaches : https://regex101.com/ & http://txt2re.com/

Comment: No.. I want to check strings that starts with 'XX'

Comment: In that case you don't even need regex, just use `indexOf`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simply try

```
var filteredMatches = arr.filter(function(val){
  return val.indexOf("XX") == 0;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use JavaScript `.startsWith()` method.

```js
var arr = [ "ABCDS ", "XXDER ", "DERHJ ", "XXUIO" ];

var filteredArr = arr.filter(function(val){
  return val.startsWith("XX");
});

console.log(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
var arr = [ "ABCDS ", "XXDER ", "DERHJ ", "XXUIO" ];
// match if two letters at the beginning are the same
var re = new RegExp('^([a-zA-Z])\\1');
var filteredArr = arr.filter(function(val) {
  return re.test(val);
});
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var filteredArr = [];
 var arr = [ "ABCDS ", "XXDER ", "DERHJ ", "XXUIO" ];
 var re = new RegExp('^XX');
 jQuery.each( arr, function( i, val ) {

 if(re.test(val )){
 filteredArr.push(val);
 }
});
```

- ^ means match at the beginning of the line

Answer (score 0):

I suggest string match :

```js
var arr = [ "ABCDS ", "XXDER ", "DERHJ ", "XXUIO" ];

var r = arr.filter(x => x.match(/^XX/))

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` with a less-complex regex:

```
var filtered = arr.filter(function (el) {
  return /^X{2}/.test(el);
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/m9bLx90c/)